# A generalized quadratic loss for deep neural network for multi-class classification

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, loss-function

I'm evaluating the possibility to introduce a new loss for the subject described above.
Let [image] be the number of examples, [image] the number of classes,
[image] the [image] classifier output on example [image] and [image] the binary indicator (0 or 1) if class label [image] is the correct classification for the observation on pattern [image]. It would be:

[image]

where the cross-entropy loss is used and c.e. losses are correlated by a similarity matrix `S` positive semi-definite.

Is there any method to write this custom loss on a software framework for deep learning (e.g.: TensorFlow) and have a backtracking algorithm that is based on it?

While the feed-forward-->backtracking cycle advances, new patterns are processed by the Neural Network. Being so, new errors are determined:
[image] where `x` is the number of feed-forward steps.

So It should be possible to backtrack using the loss:

[image]

where `x` is the number of feed-forward steps.

In case you can help me, we can be co-authors of a paper about this subject.

Comment: Hi, can you please write the formulas in a different format? I suppose that's Latex, but it does not help because it's shown as plain text

Comment: Sorry, I' don't know the exact format to use in this editor in order to render formulas.

Comment: I used some 3rd party editor to correct this: https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php. Please verify if they look as expected.

Comment: I've installed Theano and I'm trying to undestand how to build a cost based on S on a MultiLayerPerceptron example that I have found on the net.
The MLNN works for the MNIST dataset, but I can't figure yout of to insert pattern correlation inside the cost function.

Comment: The original cost function is:

 `cost = (
        classifier.negative_log_likelihood(y)
        + L1_reg * classifier.L1
        + L2_reg * classifier.L2_sqr
    )`

Comment: I wrote a custom loss within the mlpack forum github. I'm still not able to produce results because I can't transpose an arma:::rowvec variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tensorflow within Python and create a custom model with your loss. This is in my experience/opinion the most accessible way to achieve custom behavior:

Your model could look like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras import losses


class CustomLossModel(Model):
    def __init__(self, inner_model):
        super().__init__()

        self.model = inner_model  # any tf.keras.Model that fit your needs
        self.cce = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(
            from_logits=False,  # you have to apply softmax at your last layer
            reduction=losses.Reduction.NONE
        )

        self.loss_tracker = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='loss')

    def call(self, x, training=False):
        return self.model(x, training)

    # your loss implementation, I hope I got it right
    def custom_loss(self, y_true, y_pred, sim_matrix):
        cce_loss = self.cce(y_true, y_pred)
        sim_loss = cce_loss * sim_matrix
        total_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
            cce_loss * tf.reduce_sum(sim_loss, axis=-1))
        return total_loss
        
    @tf.function
    def train_step(self, x, y, sim_matrix):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            pred = self(x, training=True)
            loss = self.custom_loss(y, pred, sim_matrix)

        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.trainable_variables)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(
            zip(gradients, self.trainable_variables))

        self.loss_tracker.update_state(loss)
        return {self.loss_tracker.name: self.loss_tracker.result()}
```

IMPORTANT NOTE: with alternating the input parameters of `train_step` you will not be able to use `.fit` function built in for tensorflow classes `Model` and  `Sequential`. You will have to write your own routine.  There are other ways to rewrite the `train_step`, but I wanted to keep it simple.

Example usage:

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential, Input
from tensorflow.keras import layers

imodel = Sequential()
imodel.add(Input(10))  # 10 input features
imodel.add(layers.Dense(100, activation="relu"))
imodel.add(layers.Dense(4, activation="softmax"))  # 4 classes

clm = CustomLossModel(imodel)
clm.compile(optimizer="adam")

x = tf.random.normal((5, 10))  # 5 samples, 10 features
y = tf.convert_to_tensor([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                          [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
                          [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
                          [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0],
                          [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]])  # 5 samples, 4 classes
sim_matrix = tf.random.uniform((5, 5), 0, 1)  #  5 x 5 matrix for the sample similarities
indices = [[i, i] for i in range(5)]
# similarity of sample to itself is 1.0, therefore this update is necessary for the example case
sim_matrix = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(sim_matrix, indices, [1 for _ in range(5)])

# you can incorporate the call of the `train_step` within any loop
# you just have to provide the needed tensors x, y, sim_matrix
output = clm.train_step(x, y, sim_matrix)
print(output)
```

This will generate the following output: `{'loss': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=6.3116484>}`

I hope, this will answer your question and that I implemented the loss, the way you intended. Otherwise, I can for sure make the required changes.